# how to update a dataframe with another filtered dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have 2 dataframes. I need to update a column in the first one with the average of values in the second one, grouped by index. 
here an example
df1 (col1 is the index)

```
      col2 col3
col1           
a        0    X
b        0    0
c        0    0
d        0    0
```

df2 (col1 is the index)

```
    col2  col3
col1            
a        1     0
a        3     0
d        2     0
d        4     0
```

I need the average in df2's col2 (a=2, d=3) and update df1 only for the rows with col3 = X

I tried this

```
df1.loc[df1.col3=='X'].update(df2.groupby(df2.index),'col2'].mean().to_frame())
```

It works only if I don't use loc.

the result I'm trying to have
df1 (col1 is the index)

```
    col2 col3
col1           
a        2    X
b        0    0
c        0    0
d        0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
m=df2.groupby(df2.index).col2.mean()
df1.loc[df1.col3=='X','col2']=m
print(df1)
```

---

```
      col2 col3
col1           
a        2    X
b        0    0
c        0    0
d        0    0
```